# Why is operator<< not found if defined in namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, operator-overloading, iostream

In the code below, I get an error when trying to print `time_point` to the console. It goes away if I move `operator<<` outside of `my_namespace`. Why is this? Must I define my `operator<<` function in the global namespace?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <date/date.h>

namespace my_namespace {

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os,
                         const std::chrono::system_clock::time_point &time_point) {
  return os << date::format(
      "%F %T\n",
      std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(time_point));
}

}

int main() {

  std::chrono::system_clock::time_point time_point{
      std::chrono::milliseconds{1000}};
  std::cout << time_point;

}
```

Comment: Unqualified name lookup only searches the current namespace and the ones outside enclosing namespaces including the global scope. Since both the arguments are from the `std` namespace, you don't get any help from ADL either.

Comment: It's not an answer, just a frame challange. If name lookup could always find things regardless of what namespace they are declared in, how could one ever avoid conflicts? Why would one use namespaces at all in such a system?

Comment: [Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup) are some details about unqualified name lookup.

Comment: Thank you all. I'll read up on unqualified name lookup. So, to define a `operator<<` overload which allows a time point to be written to a stream, is the only way to define it in the global namespace?

Comment: Have you tried ```std::cout << (my_namespace::operator<< time_point) << std::endl;```?

Comment: You can use your overloaded operator outside of namespace it has been declared in by using its qualified name, i.e. `my_namespace::operator<<(std::cout, time_point);`.

Comment: Functions that are defined in your namespace will see that insertion operator.